Is addition always closed?
I am currently studying group theory on my own and had two questions:

Are there any mathematical structures for which addition is not closed? For example, the sum of two integers is always an integer, the sum of two n-dimensional vectors is always a vector and so they are closed under addition.

Is it possible to perform addition between two elements of different mathematical structures and obtain a result? A poor example is the sum of a real number and a complex number, which produces a complex number. This example is poor because all real numbers are complex, and I am looking for an example where one set is not a subset of the other.


More generally, how is the addition operator defined? What are some universal laws that follow for all structures and what are unique to some structures (such as for matrices, where corresponding elements are added)?

The set of all invertible 2 by 2 matrices is not closed under addition. The set of irrational numbers is not closed under addition.

The set of all odd numbers is not closed under addition.

What do you mean by "addition" in "any mathematical structure"?  Usually the name is used only for an operation that is both associative and commutative, i.e. the binary operation of a commutative semigroup or monoid.

A structure can be anything.  So you can have have a set that simply doesn't contain all the sums of any two elements and that will not be closed under addition.  $S = {1,3,4, 8}$ is not closed under addition.

Second example:  Water + Dirt = mud.  It sounds like I'm joking but how exactly do you define "addition"?  We can certainly define ways to combine one type of an object with another to get a third why can't we call that addition.  (Ex: Let $A={a,b}$ and $B={1,2}$ and $C={fish, taco, cat}$ and $f:A\times B \to C$ via $(a,1)\to fish;(a,2)\to taco;(b,1)\to cat; (b,2)\to fish$.  That's a valid function.  Why can't a call it "addition" and say $a + 2 = taco$?)

“how is the addition operator defined” the way you want it to be. Now you are studying things from a pure abstract perspective. How you define the operation is up to you as long as the operation meets certain requirements.

@fleablood does that mean the addition operation can be defined as anything and the reason we do it the way we do for simpler sets like Z and R is because it's comparatively useful for higher mathematics?

That wasn't really my intent.  I was trying to offer "socratic dialog" to get you to tighten and think about the concept of what exactly "addition" means and what or the "objects" that it must be closed on.  I rather like ultralegends definition of "addition" that it is a two argument function from a cartesian product of a set $X$ from $X\times X\to X$. As such a construction it "forces" addition to be closed.  But that raises the question about what about "odd integers". Can we refer to addition of subsets of the univeral object. I think so but... we have to make our consistent definitions.

You know, when socrates button-holed his audience so they turned and said "Okay, if you're so smart, why don't you tell us.  What's the answer?", he'd say "I don't know; I'm just as stupid as anyone else".  So when you ask me "does that mean the addition operation can be defined as anything and the reason we do it the way we do for simpler sets like Z and R is because it's comparatively useful for higher mathematics", I answer "I don't. I don't know what 'addition' technically means"

Usually, addition (in a set $X$) is defined as a map $p\colon X\times X\to X$. You call $a+b=p((a,b))$. This forces addition to be closed. The problem is, when you have a set $X$, it is like you only know $X$, that is your universe, and you don't know what anything outside $X$ even is like. You want to define addition, which means for every pair $a$ and $b$ in $X$, you want to make sense of $a+b$. Where could that possibly be? In $X$.
So, one way that you can have addition be not closed is as follows: Take a sub-universe of $X$, then sometimes the sum may land outside the sub-universe, and then the sub-universe is not closed under addition. Take the usual addition in $\Bbb Z$, and consider the set of all prime numbers, $P$. Then, $3\in P$, $5\in P$ but $3+5\notin P$. If you want that the other group axioms hold as well (but not closure), you can just look at $P\cup(-P)\cup\{0\}$. (By $-P$, I just mean $\{-x:x\in P\}$.)

For the second question, sure. Take any three sets that have nothing to do with each other, say $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ and arbitrarily define a map $X\times Y\to Z$ and that is one possible addition. Take for example addition between $\mathbb Z$, $M_2(\mathbb R)$ (the set of $2\times2$ matrices with real entries), and $M_3(\mathbb C)$ (the set of $3\times 3$ matrices with complex entries) and define
$$n+\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}n&0&0\\0&a&b\\0&c&d\end{bmatrix}$$
(This is actually a thing commonly used, and is called the direct sum of matrices. Actually, that is almost the direct sum, you just need to look at $n$ as a $1\times1$ complex matrix, and the $2\times2$ real matrix as a complex matrix.)

As for your last question, there is no universally accepted definition of addition. It can be any map that takes pairs to some elements, or even anything more general, it is completely upto you. Usually though, when addition is mentioned, it is assumed that it is at least commutative and associative (and often even assumed that it gives an abelian group structure to the underlying set).
Hope this helps. :)

Your definition in your second answer almost seems as a forced definition to make the question work. Is there a more natural way to add two different structures? Possibly using high school math?

But $3+5=8\notin P\cup(-P)\cup{0}$.

@AM_: As I said, the example is very natural. It will make sense when you study some advanced linear algebra. It is called the direct sum of matrices. In high school, the only things you know are complex numbers (and matrices). And this is a very natural example of adding numbers and matrices. I don't think there are more structures to even come up with an example.

@Shaun: Sorry, I don't get what you are trying to say.

That $P\cup(-P)\cup{0}$ is not closed.

@Shaun: In case you got confused, $P\cup(-P)\cup{0}$ is a structure where the other group axioms (associativity, existence of identity and inverses) hold but not closure.
